# myslqdump shell command error

Tags: linux, shell, command, mysql

```
mysqldump -S /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock -u root -h localhost -p gihan mistoria wp_posts |  gzip -9 >/opt/lampp/htdocs/mistoria/wp-content/backups/backup_table.sql.gz
```

This is my command once insert this command it's returning following error please help me out.

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'gihan' when selecting the database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between "-p" and the password.

```
mysqldump -S /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock -u root -h localhost -pgihan mistoria wp_posts |  gzip -9 >/opt/lampp/htdocs/mistoria/wp-content/backups/backup_table.sql.gz
```